# Do Google AdSense and Patreon accounts lead to a 1099-Misc if I choose not to withraw the balance?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099

Does the 1099-Misc come from the money paid out into my bank account, or the money "earned" into these online accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just earning the money would trigger a 1099 (assuming other requirements are met).  It doesn't matter where the money is.

Answer (score -1):

Form 1099-misc reports PAYMENTS, not earnings.  This does not imply the EARNINGS are not taxable in the year they were earned.